# Post array of products in shopify

Tags: c#, shopify, shopify-api

Trying to post array of products using c# httpClinet to shopify.But getting 400 bad request. Also tried to post array of product = new object like items, but also getting 400 code.

```
var arrayOfProducts = new
        {
            products = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    title = "qqwqw",
                    description = "test",
                    product_type = "Game",
                    vendor = "test"
                },
                new
                {
                    title = "1233eewq",
                    description = "test",
                    product_type = "Game",
                    vendor = "test"
                }
            }
        };
        var resp = await http.PostAsync($"{_shopify.Path}/products.json", new StringContent(
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(arrayOfProducts)
        , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), stoppingToken);
```

Comment: What is the error message in the response?, along with 400 you would also receive the message

Comment: no message. only 400